# Instantiating a class in different namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I am stuck with a namespace conflict. My class file looks like this (in short). I have written comment `stuck here` where i am having the problem.

```
<?php
//file location - /core/controller/EH_Loader.php

namespace core\controller;

class EH_Loader {

    //some public functions here...

    private function _create_instance($type, $class, $params, $method_name, $data) {


        //create a reflection class so that we can pass parameters to the constructor


        // class_alias('Application\Controller\\'.$class, $class, FALSE);

        $ref_class = new \ReflectionClass(new $class()); //stuck here - more explainiantion below

        if (is_array($params) && sizeof($params) > 0) {

            $instance = $ref_class->newInstanceArgs($params);

        } else {

            $instance = new $class();
        }
        $this->logger->info("$type object created for $class class");

        //call the method along with parameters, if they exist !

        if (method_exists($instance, $method_name)) {

             call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method_name), $data);
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

`new $class` is in a different namcespace and it lies inside `/application/controller/test.php`. I am not able to load that file through psr-4. How can i achieve this. Also how can I make my `$class` file in global namespace.

EDIT: The problem is a bit more serious. The `new $class` looks like this. It extends another class which has the same namespace `namespace core\controller;`

```
//namespace application\controller;
class test extends EH_Base {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a class that is namespaced, you need to define the entire namespace. `new ReflectionClass('My\Namespace\'.$class);`. You also don't invoke `new` in the argument to the ReflectionClass method.

Comment: Yes, i tried that but didn't work. Says `Class Application\Controller\test does not exist`

Comment: You might need `new \ReflectionClass('\\My\\Namespace\\'.$class);` This is due to the fact that it is resolving to the current namespace, and then anything else aliased with the use method.